# "Cannot help" is used with a present participle to roughly the same effect as a verb form in -ing

Tags: present-participles, ing

According to the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?id=C5073200),

> **Cannot help** is used with a present participle to
> roughly the same effect as a verb form ending in -ing in a sentence
> such as *We cannot help admiring his courage*.

However I do not understand what the author refers to by "to roughly the same effect as a verb form ending in -ing".

Comment: It would be useful to know the context, to know what "the same effect" refers to. I'm guessing it's a mistake and should be something like either "Cannot help is used with a present participle to roughly the same effect in a sentence such as We cannot help admiring his courage." or "Cannot help is used with to roughly the same effect with a verb form ending in -ing in a sentence such as We cannot help admiring his courage." ("as" is commonly used in comparisons but can also refer to a purpose or manner of usage.)

Comment: @StuartF _to roughly the same effect [as cannot but + infinitive]_? https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?id=C5073200

Comment: Perhaps they're struggling to explain the behaviour of the ing-form in this particular construction. Quirk et al _did_ posit a gradience between deverbal noun (stole the painting/s) and true participle (she is/was painting). I'd just write <<  _Cannot help_ is used with an ing-form (if of a transitive verb, with object) in a sentence such as _We cannot help admiring his courage / smiling_. >>